# Word To HTML: List style to UL/OL

Tags: c#, html, css, docx

I have to create a code in `C#` where a Word document (docx) is converted to HTML. This is the easy part, using `OpenXMLTools.dll`. But the question doesn't end here. It needs to convert all the bullet points and/or numbered list in Word file to UL and/or OL respectively in the Output HTML.

I am stuck over this and I think the OpenXML Tools will not help me with this, now it would be great if anyone could push me in the right direction. I know I can render the XML part, fish out the List part and style it accordingly each part or paragraph, but the thing is I don't know how, A little help would be wonderful.

N.B: This is not an assignment.

Comment: It would be better to state a reason for down vote too.

Comment: @gerdi It is the opposite of what I want, its HTML to DOCX I want DOCX to HTML.